# Apply stroke to a textblock in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

How do you apply stroke (outline around text) to a textblock in xaml in WPF?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Below is my more idiomatically WPF, full-featured take on this. It supports pretty much everything you'd expect, including:

- all font related properties including stretch and style
- text alignment (left, right, center, justify)
- text wrapping
- text trimming
- text decorations (underline, strike through etcetera)

Here's a simple example of what can be achieved with it:

```
<local:OutlinedTextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20pt" FontWeight="ExtraBold" TextWrapping="Wrap" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{StaticResource TextStroke}" Fill="{StaticResource TextFill}">
    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit
</local:OutlinedTextBlock>
```

Which results in:

[image]

Here's the code for the control:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class OutlinedTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Fill",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Stroke",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "StrokeThickness",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStretchProperty = TextElement.FontStretchProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty = TextElement.FontStyleProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty = TextElement.FontWeightProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextInvalidated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextAlignment",
        typeof(TextAlignment),
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextDecorationsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextDecorations",
        typeof(TextDecorationCollection),
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextTrimmingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextTrimming",
        typeof(TextTrimming),
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextWrappingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextWrapping",
        typeof(TextWrapping),
        typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextWrapping.NoWrap, OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    private FormattedText formattedText;
    private Geometry textGeometry;

    public OutlinedTextBlock()
    {
        this.TextDecorations = new TextDecorationCollection();
    }

    public Brush Fill
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontStretch FontStretch
    {
        get { return (FontStretch)GetValue(FontStretchProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStretchProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get { return (FontStyle)GetValue(FontStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush Stroke
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(StrokeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeProperty, value); }
    }

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextAlignment TextAlignment
    {
        get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextDecorationCollection TextDecorations
    {
        get { return (TextDecorationCollection)this.GetValue(TextDecorationsProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TextDecorationsProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextTrimming TextTrimming
    {
        get { return (TextTrimming)GetValue(TextTrimmingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextTrimmingProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextWrapping TextWrapping
    {
        get { return (TextWrapping)GetValue(TextWrappingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextWrappingProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        this.EnsureGeometry();

        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(this.Fill, new Pen(this.Stroke, this.StrokeThickness), this.textGeometry);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        this.EnsureFormattedText();

        // constrain the formatted text according to the available size
        // the Math.Min call is important - without this constraint (which seems arbitrary, but is the maximum allowable text width), things blow up when availableSize is infinite in both directions
        // the Math.Max call is to ensure we don't hit zero, which will cause MaxTextHeight to throw
        this.formattedText.MaxTextWidth = Math.Min(3579139, availableSize.Width);
        this.formattedText.MaxTextHeight = Math.Max(0.0001d, availableSize.Height);

        // return the desired size
        return new Size(this.formattedText.Width, this.formattedText.Height);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        this.EnsureFormattedText();

        // update the formatted text with the final size
        this.formattedText.MaxTextWidth = finalSize.Width;
        this.formattedText.MaxTextHeight = finalSize.Height;

        // need to re-generate the geometry now that the dimensions have changed
        this.textGeometry = null;

        return finalSize;
    }

    private static void OnFormattedTextInvalidated(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var outlinedTextBlock = (OutlinedTextBlock)dependencyObject;
        outlinedTextBlock.formattedText = null;
        outlinedTextBlock.textGeometry = null;

        outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateMeasure();
        outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private static void OnFormattedTextUpdated(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var outlinedTextBlock = (OutlinedTextBlock)dependencyObject;
        outlinedTextBlock.UpdateFormattedText();
        outlinedTextBlock.textGeometry = null;

        outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateMeasure();
        outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private void EnsureFormattedText()
    {
        if (this.formattedText != null || this.Text == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.formattedText = new FormattedText(
            this.Text,
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
            this.FlowDirection,
            new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, FontStretches.Normal),
            this.FontSize,
            Brushes.Black);

        this.UpdateFormattedText();
    }

    private void UpdateFormattedText()
    {
        if (this.formattedText == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.formattedText.MaxLineCount = this.TextWrapping == TextWrapping.NoWrap ? 1 : int.MaxValue;
        this.formattedText.TextAlignment = this.TextAlignment;
        this.formattedText.Trimming = this.TextTrimming;

        this.formattedText.SetFontSize(this.FontSize);
        this.formattedText.SetFontStyle(this.FontStyle);
        this.formattedText.SetFontWeight(this.FontWeight);
        this.formattedText.SetFontFamily(this.FontFamily);
        this.formattedText.SetFontStretch(this.FontStretch);
        this.formattedText.SetTextDecorations(this.TextDecorations);
    }

    private void EnsureGeometry()
    {
        if (this.textGeometry != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.EnsureFormattedText();
        this.textGeometry = this.formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: this would be fantastic if the stroke was outside of the letters. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: When using TemplateBinding with the Text property I get a null object exception. Appears to be from the MeasureOverride function where formattedText is null

Comment: I added a this immediately after this.EnsureFormattedText(); in the MeasureOverride

Comment: looks like you are missing "using System;" so your reference to Math resolves.

Comment: I get the error 'MaxTextHeight' property value must be greater than zero. The available height is 0, this might be a problem.

Comment: @Wouter: yeah, just add a `Math.Max` call when assigning `MaxTextHeight`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am trying to use this with text blocks that are bound to a view model, it looks like when its doing the calculation the text is always null and an error is thrown in ArrangeOverride when trying to set the MaxTextHeight to 0. Any thoughts?

Comment: I put a try catch around the ArrangeOverride's setting on MaxTextWidth and MaxTextHeight and it seems to work for me again, even when using a viewmodel. I might simply check if it's 0 first and skip that step in this case. It get's called multiple times and get's it right at some point.

Comment: I have directly extended your class in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382597/how-remove-the-stroke-from-arabic-character-connection-position-on-wpf/25388303#25388303) on [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382597/how-remove-the-stroke-from-arabic-character-connection-position-on-wpf/25388303). Thank you for this control sample :-)

Comment: How do I use this? I get the error `The namespace prefix "local" is not defined.`

Comment: @Jason: map local xml namespace to whateaver namespace you put the code in. Something like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar"`

Comment: Alright, so I got this working... question... How do you set a vertical content alignment?

Comment: How might one go about setting the horizontal content and vertical content alignment? I noticed these two properties are missing... Also; why not just create a new class object based on the TextBlock class and add this new functionality to it? (I'm trying that myself using what's been provided here, so I am curious if there is anything stopping you (or me) from making that happen).

Comment: Without modifying the original code to add the content alignment, just put the text in a wrapper that be used to align it as needed. Grid comes to mind.You just need something that will fill it's container and is able to provide alignment of content.

Comment: I'm looking into using something like this to extend a label and achieve a similar effect. Reason being mostly nit-picky stuff ( I don't like how the text font properties are laid out in the UI, and I don't like that I can't supply a background). I basically just want to extend the class and provide a Stroke and StrokeWidth property ( backed by appropriate Dependency Properties, of course )... Now I just need to figure out how to pen the stroke around the in the OnRender override...

Comment: @m1m1k despite nearly 50 upvotes and lots of thank-yous? Considered that maybe the mistake is yours?

Comment: @KentBoogaart  Can't handle NULL text ( which can happen with binding ) I needed to add if null return string.empty in Text getter.

Comment: And how can I use this as MultiLine?

Answer (score 56):

I modified the most voted answer with several fixes, including:

- Fix so texts with a single line would show when using
  UseLayoutRounding.
- Outlines would show outside the text instead of in the middle of the 
  border.
- The pen is created only once instead of on each render.
- Fix so it won't crash when the text is set to null.
- Fix so outline uses proper round caps.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class OutlinedTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    private void UpdatePen() {
        _Pen = new Pen(Stroke, StrokeThickness) {
            DashCap = PenLineCap.Round,
            EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
            LineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round,
            StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round
        };

        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Fill",
      typeof(Brush),
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Stroke",
      typeof(Brush),
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, StrokePropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void StrokePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) {
        (dependencyObject as OutlinedTextBlock)?.UpdatePen();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "StrokeThickness",
      typeof(double),
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, StrokePropertyChangedCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStretchProperty = TextElement.FontStretchProperty.AddOwner(
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty = TextElement.FontStyleProperty.AddOwner(
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty = TextElement.FontWeightProperty.AddOwner(
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Text",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextInvalidated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "TextAlignment",
      typeof(TextAlignment),
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextDecorationsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "TextDecorations",
      typeof(TextDecorationCollection),
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextTrimmingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "TextTrimming",
      typeof(TextTrimming),
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextWrappingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "TextWrapping",
      typeof(TextWrapping),
      typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextWrapping.NoWrap, OnFormattedTextUpdated));

    private FormattedText _FormattedText;
    private Geometry _TextGeometry;
    private Pen _Pen;

    public Brush Fill
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontStretch FontStretch
    {
        get { return (FontStretch)GetValue(FontStretchProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStretchProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get { return (FontStyle)GetValue(FontStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush Stroke
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(StrokeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeProperty, value); }
    }

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextAlignment TextAlignment
    {
        get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextDecorationCollection TextDecorations
    {
        get { return (TextDecorationCollection)GetValue(TextDecorationsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextDecorationsProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextTrimming TextTrimming
    {
        get { return (TextTrimming)GetValue(TextTrimmingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextTrimmingProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextWrapping TextWrapping
    {
        get { return (TextWrapping)GetValue(TextWrappingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextWrappingProperty, value); }
    }

    public OutlinedTextBlock() {
        UpdatePen();
        TextDecorations = new TextDecorationCollection();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {
        EnsureGeometry();

        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, _Pen, _TextGeometry);
        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Fill, null, _TextGeometry);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) {
        EnsureFormattedText();

        // constrain the formatted text according to the available size

        double w = availableSize.Width;
        double h = availableSize.Height;

        // the Math.Min call is important - without this constraint (which seems arbitrary, but is the maximum allowable text width), things blow up when availableSize is infinite in both directions
        // the Math.Max call is to ensure we don't hit zero, which will cause MaxTextHeight to throw
        _FormattedText.MaxTextWidth = Math.Min(3579139, w);
        _FormattedText.MaxTextHeight = Math.Max(0.0001d, h);

        // return the desired size
        return new Size(Math.Ceiling(_FormattedText.Width), Math.Ceiling(_FormattedText.Height));
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) {
        EnsureFormattedText();

        // update the formatted text with the final size
        _FormattedText.MaxTextWidth = finalSize.Width;
        _FormattedText.MaxTextHeight = Math.Max(0.0001d, finalSize.Height);

        // need to re-generate the geometry now that the dimensions have changed
        _TextGeometry = null;

        return finalSize;
    }

    private static void OnFormattedTextInvalidated(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
      DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var outlinedTextBlock = (OutlinedTextBlock)dependencyObject;
        outlinedTextBlock._FormattedText = null;
        outlinedTextBlock._TextGeometry = null;

        outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateMeasure();
        outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private static void OnFormattedTextUpdated(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var outlinedTextBlock = (OutlinedTextBlock)dependencyObject;
        outlinedTextBlock.UpdateFormattedText();
        outlinedTextBlock._TextGeometry = null;

        outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateMeasure();
        outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private void EnsureFormattedText() {
        if (_FormattedText != null) {
            return;
        }

        _FormattedText = new FormattedText(
          Text ?? "",
          CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
          FlowDirection,
          new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch),
          FontSize,
          Brushes.Black);

        UpdateFormattedText();
    }

    private void UpdateFormattedText() {
        if (_FormattedText == null) {
            return;
        }

        _FormattedText.MaxLineCount = TextWrapping == TextWrapping.NoWrap ? 1 : int.MaxValue;
        _FormattedText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment;
        _FormattedText.Trimming = TextTrimming;

        _FormattedText.SetFontSize(FontSize);
        _FormattedText.SetFontStyle(FontStyle);
        _FormattedText.SetFontWeight(FontWeight);
        _FormattedText.SetFontFamily(FontFamily);
        _FormattedText.SetFontStretch(FontStretch);
        _FormattedText.SetTextDecorations(TextDecorations);
    }

    private void EnsureGeometry() {
        if (_TextGeometry != null) {
            return;
        }

        EnsureFormattedText();
        _TextGeometry = _FormattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this adds perfection to the previous solution. Why nobody upvoted you?

Comment: I guess the question is too old, WPF isn't that hot anymore or a mix of both? :)

Comment: WPF is HOT! so only the first chance remains

Comment: Upvoted. Recommend removing the using Skirmish.Util.Helpers line, however.

Comment: I still get the outlines in the middle of the border.         `<local:OutlinedTextBlock Stroke="Red" FontSize="22" Fill="Transparent" StrokeThickness="2">
            abc
        </local:OutlinedTextBlock>`

Comment: Yes, that's because you are using fill transparent, so the fill cannot actually fill the inner half of the outline.

Answer (score 34):

Found It.  Not so easy to do apparently, there is no built in Stroke text in WPF (kind of a big missing feature if you ask me).  First create the custom class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace CustomXaml
{

public class OutlinedText : FrameworkElement, IAddChild
{
    #region Private Fields

    private Geometry _textGeometry;

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when a dependency property has changed. Generate a new FormattedText object to display.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">OutlineText object whose property was updated.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments for the dependency property.</param>
    private static void OnOutlineTextInvalidated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((OutlinedText)d).CreateText();
    }

    #endregion


    #region FrameworkElement Overrides

    /// <summary>
    /// OnRender override draws the geometry of the text and optional highlight.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">Drawing context of the OutlineText control.</param>
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        CreateText();
        // Draw the outline based on the properties that are set.
        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Fill, new Pen(Stroke, StrokeThickness), _textGeometry);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the outline geometry based on the formatted text.
    /// </summary>
    public void CreateText()
    {
        FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
        FontWeight fontWeight = FontWeights.Medium;

        if (Bold == true) fontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        if (Italic == true) fontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;

        // Create the formatted text based on the properties set.
        FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
            Text,
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),                
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(Font, fontStyle, fontWeight, FontStretches.Normal),                
            FontSize,
            Brushes.Black // This brush does not matter since we use the geometry of the text. 
            );

        // Build the geometry object that represents the text.
        _textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));




        //set the size of the custome control based on the size of the text
        this.MinWidth = formattedText.Width;
        this.MinHeight = formattedText.Height;

    }

    #endregion

    #region DependencyProperties

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies whether the font should display Bold font weight.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Bold
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(BoldProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(BoldProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the Bold dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoldProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Bold",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            false,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutlineTextInvalidated),
            null
            )
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the brush to use for the fill of the formatted text.
    /// </summary>
    public Brush Fill
    {
        get
        {
            return (Brush)GetValue(FillProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(FillProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the Fill dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Fill",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSteelBlue),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutlineTextInvalidated),
            null
            )
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// The font to use for the displayed formatted text.
    /// </summary>
    public FontFamily Font
    {
        get
        {
            return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(FontProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the Font dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Font",
        typeof(FontFamily),
        typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new FontFamily("Arial"),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutlineTextInvalidated),
            null
            )
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// The current font size.
    /// </summary>
    public double FontSize
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the FontSize dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FontSize",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             (double)48.0,
             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
             new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutlineTextInvalidated),
             null
             )
        );


    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies whether the font should display Italic font style.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Italic
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(ItalicProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ItalicProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the Italic dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItalicProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Italic",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             false,
             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
             new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutlineTextInvalidated),
             null
             )
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the brush to use for the stroke and optional hightlight of the formatted text.
    /// </summary>
    public Brush Stroke
    {
        get
        {
            return (Brush)GetValue(StrokeProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(StrokeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the Stroke dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Stroke",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Teal),
             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
             new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutlineTextInvalidated),
             null
             )
        );

    /// <summary>
    ///     The stroke thickness of the font.
    /// </summary>
    public ushort StrokeThickness
    {
        get
        {
            return (ushort)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the StrokeThickness dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "StrokeThickness",
        typeof(ushort),
        typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             (ushort)0,
             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
             new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutlineTextInvalidated),
             null
             )
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the text string to display.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the Text dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             "",
             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
             new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutlineTextInvalidated),
             null
             )
        );

    public void AddChild(Object value)
    {

    }

    public void AddText(string value)
    {
        Text = value;
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

The you can reference it in your xaml.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:CustomXaml;assembly=CustomXaml">
    <Grid>
        <customControls:OutlinedText x:Name="TextContent" Fill="#ffffffff" FontSize="28"     
Bold="True" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Text="Back" Margin="10,0,10,0" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: This worked really well for me, but I also needed word wrapping and text alignment.  
This is easily done using the FormattedText.MaxTextWidth and FormattedText.TextAlignment properties.

Comment: Awesome! Note that IAddChild is deprecated. Instead attribute the class with [ContentProperty("Text")] then you can set the text directly in XAML as in:
<customControls:OutlinedText ... >The text!</customControls:OutlinedText>

Comment: This is awesome. Since this answer is a  little old now, is there any other way of achieving this or is this still the best approach? +1

Comment: Stuff like this aren't "features", they are "effects".

Comment: @PatrickMagee I'm from 2019 and this works perfectly! (.NET Framework 4.6.1)

Answer (score 18):

I modified [@Javier G. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262509/5508373)

- Stroke position can be: center, outside or Inside, the default
  is outside.
- Fill can be transparent.

Center:

[image]

Outside:

[image]

Inside:

[image]

Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public enum StrokePosition
    {
        Center,
        Outside,
        Inside
    }

    [ContentProperty("Text")]
    public class OutlinedTextBlock : FrameworkElement
    {
        private void UpdatePen()
        {
            _Pen = new Pen(Stroke, StrokeThickness)
            {
                DashCap = PenLineCap.Round,
                EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
                LineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round,
                StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round
            };

            if (StrokePosition == StrokePosition.Outside || StrokePosition == StrokePosition.Inside)
            {
                _Pen.Thickness = StrokeThickness * 2;
            }

            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        public StrokePosition StrokePosition
        {
            get { return (StrokePosition)GetValue(StrokePositionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokePositionProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokePositionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StrokePosition", 
                typeof(StrokePosition),
                typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(StrokePosition.Outside, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Fill",
          typeof(Brush),
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Stroke",
          typeof(Brush),
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "StrokeThickness",
          typeof(double),
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStretchProperty = TextElement.FontStretchProperty.AddOwner(
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty = TextElement.FontStyleProperty.AddOwner(
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty = TextElement.FontWeightProperty.AddOwner(
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Text",
          typeof(string),
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextInvalidated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "TextAlignment",
          typeof(TextAlignment),
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextDecorationsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "TextDecorations",
          typeof(TextDecorationCollection),
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextTrimmingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "TextTrimming",
          typeof(TextTrimming),
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextWrappingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "TextWrapping",
          typeof(TextWrapping),
          typeof(OutlinedTextBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextWrapping.NoWrap, OnFormattedTextUpdated));

        private FormattedText _FormattedText;
        private Geometry _TextGeometry;
        private Pen _Pen;
        private PathGeometry _clipGeometry;

        public Brush Fill
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
        }

        public FontFamily FontFamily
        {
            get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
        }

        [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
        public double FontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public FontStretch FontStretch
        {
            get { return (FontStretch)GetValue(FontStretchProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FontStretchProperty, value); }
        }

        public FontStyle FontStyle
        {
            get { return (FontStyle)GetValue(FontStyleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FontStyleProperty, value); }
        }

        public FontWeight FontWeight
        {
            get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush Stroke
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(StrokeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeProperty, value); }
        }

        public double StrokeThickness
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public TextAlignment TextAlignment
        {
            get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value); }
        }

        public TextDecorationCollection TextDecorations
        {
            get { return (TextDecorationCollection)GetValue(TextDecorationsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextDecorationsProperty, value); }
        }

        public TextTrimming TextTrimming
        {
            get { return (TextTrimming)GetValue(TextTrimmingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextTrimmingProperty, value); }
        }

        public TextWrapping TextWrapping
        {
            get { return (TextWrapping)GetValue(TextWrappingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextWrappingProperty, value); }
        }

        public OutlinedTextBlock()
        {
            UpdatePen();
            TextDecorations = new TextDecorationCollection();
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            EnsureGeometry();

            drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Fill, null, _TextGeometry);

            if (StrokePosition == StrokePosition.Outside)
            {
                drawingContext.PushClip(_clipGeometry);
            }
            else if (StrokePosition == StrokePosition.Inside)
            {
                drawingContext.PushClip(_TextGeometry);
            }

            drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, _Pen, _TextGeometry);

            if (StrokePosition == StrokePosition.Outside || StrokePosition == StrokePosition.Inside)
            {
                drawingContext.Pop();
            }
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            EnsureFormattedText();

            // constrain the formatted text according to the available size

            double w = availableSize.Width;
            double h = availableSize.Height;

            // the Math.Min call is important - without this constraint (which seems arbitrary, but is the maximum allowable text width), things blow up when availableSize is infinite in both directions
            // the Math.Max call is to ensure we don't hit zero, which will cause MaxTextHeight to throw
            _FormattedText.MaxTextWidth = Math.Min(3579139, w);
            _FormattedText.MaxTextHeight = Math.Max(0.0001d, h);

            // return the desired size
            return new Size(Math.Ceiling(_FormattedText.Width), Math.Ceiling(_FormattedText.Height));
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            EnsureFormattedText();

            // update the formatted text with the final size
            _FormattedText.MaxTextWidth = finalSize.Width;
            _FormattedText.MaxTextHeight = Math.Max(0.0001d, finalSize.Height);

            // need to re-generate the geometry now that the dimensions have changed
            _TextGeometry = null;
            UpdatePen();

            return finalSize;
        }

        private static void OnFormattedTextInvalidated(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
          DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var outlinedTextBlock = (OutlinedTextBlock)dependencyObject;
            outlinedTextBlock._FormattedText = null;
            outlinedTextBlock._TextGeometry = null;

            outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateMeasure();
            outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateVisual();
        }

        private static void OnFormattedTextUpdated(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var outlinedTextBlock = (OutlinedTextBlock)dependencyObject;
            outlinedTextBlock.UpdateFormattedText();
            outlinedTextBlock._TextGeometry = null;

            outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateMeasure();
            outlinedTextBlock.InvalidateVisual();
        }

        private void EnsureFormattedText()
        {
            if (_FormattedText != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _FormattedText = new FormattedText(
              Text ?? "",
              CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
              FlowDirection,
              new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch),
              FontSize,
              Brushes.Black);

            UpdateFormattedText();
        }

        private void UpdateFormattedText()
        {
            if (_FormattedText == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _FormattedText.MaxLineCount = TextWrapping == TextWrapping.NoWrap ? 1 : int.MaxValue;
            _FormattedText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment;
            _FormattedText.Trimming = TextTrimming;

            _FormattedText.SetFontSize(FontSize);
            _FormattedText.SetFontStyle(FontStyle);
            _FormattedText.SetFontWeight(FontWeight);
            _FormattedText.SetFontFamily(FontFamily);
            _FormattedText.SetFontStretch(FontStretch);
            _FormattedText.SetTextDecorations(TextDecorations);
        }

        private void EnsureGeometry()
        {
            if (_TextGeometry != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            EnsureFormattedText();
            _TextGeometry = _FormattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));

            if (StrokePosition == StrokePosition.Outside)
            {
                var boundsGeo = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
                _clipGeometry = Geometry.Combine(boundsGeo, _TextGeometry, GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, null);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Grid Margin="12" Background="Bisque">
    <local:OutlinedTextBlock Stroke="Red" 
                             ClipToBounds="False"
                             FontSize="56" 
                             Fill="Transparent"
                             StrokePosition="Inside"
                             StrokeThickness="1" Text=" abc">
    </local:OutlinedTextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Sadly only has one drawback - the left and right of the stroke can get clipped if on the outside. This is event with ClipToBounds set to false. Example: http://niftymonkey.uk/hpserverpublic/Images/Http_Linked/StrokeClip.png

Comment: Found a quick + dirty hack. In `EnsureGeometry` change to this line:

`Dim boundsGeo = New RectangleGeometry(New Rect(-(2 * StrokeThickness), -(2 * StrokeThickness), ActualWidth + (4 * StrokeThickness), ActualHeight + (4 * StrokeThickness)))`

Answer (score 6):

you should wrap the TextBlock with a Border.. something like this:

```
    <Border BorderBrush="Purple" BorderThickness="2">
        <TextBlock>My fancy TextBlock</TextBlock>
    </Border>
```

in the off chance you are asking how to put a stroke around the actual letters (and not the whole TextBlock) you may want to look at using a BitmapEffect of Glow and setting the parameters on the Glow to be the stroke color you want, etc. Otherwise you may have to create something custom.

Comment: It's worth noting that BitmapEffect is now obselete - it's been replaced by the Effect class without porting all the features from BitmapEffect :(

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a regular Textblock, but apply a custom effect to it.

Combining this [Shader tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/994276/Shader-Effects-in-WPF-The-basics) and the [Prewitt Edge Detection Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt_operator) I managed to get a decent outline effect around text. While it has the advantage of rendering using the GPU, and **applying to ANY UIElement**, I'd say that @Kent Boogaart's answer looks a little better, and the EdgeResponse is finicky - I had to play with it a lot to get a nice outline.

The end result in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:EdgeDetectionEffect x:Key="OutlineEffect"
            x:Shared="false"
            EdgeResponse=".44"
            ActualHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}, Path=ActualHeight}"
            ActualWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="The Crazy Brown Fox Jumped Over the Lazy Dog."
        FontWeight="Bold"
        FontSize="25"
        Foreground="Yellow"
        Effect="{StaticResource OutlineEffect}"/>
</Grid>
```

In order to create the custom effect, I first created the EdgeDetectionColorEffect.fx (hdld) file - this is the code the GPU uses to filter the image. I compiled it in Visual Studio Command Prompt with the command:

fxc /T ps_2_0 /E main /Focc.ps EdgeDetectionColorEffect.fx

```
sampler2D Input : register(s0);
float ActualWidth : register(c0);
float ActualHeight : register(c1);
float4 OutlineColor : register(c2);
float EdgeDetectionResponse : register(c3);

float4 GetNeighborPixel(float2 pixelPoint, float xOffset, float yOffset)
{
    float2 NeighborPoint = {pixelPoint.x + xOffset, pixelPoint.y + yOffset};
    return tex2D(Input, NeighborPoint);
}

// pixel locations:
// 00 01 02
// 10 11 12
// 20 21 22
float main(float2 pixelPoint : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{

     float wo = 1 / ActualWidth; //WidthOffset
     float ho = 1 / ActualHeight; //HeightOffset

    float4 c00 = GetNeighborPixel(pixelPoint, -wo, -ho); // color of the pixel up and to the left of me.
    float4 c01 = GetNeighborPixel(pixelPoint,  00, -ho);        
    float4 c02 = GetNeighborPixel(pixelPoint,  wo, -ho);
    float4 c10 = GetNeighborPixel(pixelPoint, -wo,   0);
    float4 c11 = tex2D(Input, pixelPoint); // this is the current pixel
    float4 c12 = GetNeighborPixel(pixelPoint,  wo,   0);
    float4 c20 = GetNeighborPixel(pixelPoint, -wo,  ho);
    float4 c21 = GetNeighborPixel(pixelPoint,   0,  ho);
    float4 c22 = GetNeighborPixel(pixelPoint,  wo,  ho);

    float t00 = c00.r + c00.g + c00.b; //total of color channels
    float t01 = c01.r + c01.g + c01.b;
    float t02 = c02.r + c02.g + c02.b;
    float t10 = c10.r + c10.g + c10.b;
    float t11 = c11.r + c11.g + c11.b;
    float t12 = c12.r + c12.g + c12.b;
    float t20 = c20.r + c20.g + c20.b;
    float t21 = c21.r + c21.g + c21.b;
    float t22 = c22.r + c22.g + c22.b;

    //Prewitt - convolve the 9 pixels with:
    //       01 01 01        01 00 -1
    // Gy =  00 00 00   Gx = 01 00 -1
    //       -1 -1 -1        01 00 -1

    float gy = 0.0;  float gx = 0.0;
    gy += t00;       gx += t00;
    gy += t01;       gx += t10;
    gy += t02;       gx += t20;
    gy -= t20;       gx -= t02;
    gy -= t21;       gx -= t12;
    gy -= t22;       gx -= t22;

    if((gy*gy + gx*gx) > EdgeDetectionResponse)
    {
        return OutlineColor;
    }

    return c11;
}
```

Here's the wpf effect class:

```
public class EdgeDetectionEffect : ShaderEffect
{
    private static PixelShader _shader = new PixelShader { UriSource = new Uri("path to your compiled shader probably called cc.ps", UriKind.Absolute) };

public EdgeDetectionEffect()
{
    PixelShader = _shader;
    UpdateShaderValue(InputProperty);
    UpdateShaderValue(ActualHeightProperty);
    UpdateShaderValue(ActualWidthProperty);
    UpdateShaderValue(OutlineColorProperty);
    UpdateShaderValue(EdgeResponseProperty);
}

public Brush Input
{
     get => (Brush)GetValue(InputProperty);
     set => SetValue(InputProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = 
    ShaderEffect.RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty(nameof(Input), 
    typeof(EdgeDetectionEffect), 0);

public double ActualWidth
{
     get => (double)GetValue(ActualWidthProperty);
     set => SetValue(ActualWidthProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualWidthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ActualWidth), typeof(double), typeof(EdgeDetectionEffect),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(0)));

public double ActualHeight
{
     get => (double)GetValue(ActualHeightProperty);
     set => SetValue(ActualHeightProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualHeightProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ActualHeight), typeof(double), typeof(EdgeDetectionEffect),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(1)));

public Color OutlineColor
{
     get => (Color)GetValue(OutlineColorProperty);
     set => SetValue(OutlineColorProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineColorProperty=
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(OutlineColor), typeof(Color), typeof(EdgeDetectionEffect),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.Black, PixelShaderConstantCallback(2)));

public double EdgeResponse
{
     get => (double)GetValue(EdgeResponseProperty);
     set => SetValue(EdgeResponseProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty EdgeResponseProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(EdgeResponse), typeof(double), typeof(EdgeDetectionEffect),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(4.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(3)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

["How to: Create Outlined Text" on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816.aspx) has all the information you need.

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Comment: Try this: [link(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745816(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Yet another new url: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If applied for anyone, here a simple solution using ONLY XAML. I am not sure if it performs better or worse, but in my opinion, it looks better then any other solution above.
I wrap it in a `ContentControl` Style (and Template), following this Old School example :)
http://oldschooldotnet.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/fancy-fonts-in-xaml-silverlight-and-wpf.html

```
<Style x:Key="OutlinedText" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <!-- Some Style Setters -->
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Outlined Text"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <!-- Border Brush Must be equal '0' because TextBlock that emulate the stroke will using the BorderBrush as to define 'Stroke' color-->
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <!-- Border Brush define 'Stroke' Color-->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Seoge UI Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=FillText}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=FillText}">
                    <Canvas.Resources>
                        <!-- Style to ease the duplication of Text Blocks that emulate the stroke: Binding to one element (or to template) is the first part of the Trick -->
                        <Style x:Key="OutlinedTextStrokeTextBlock_Style" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=FillText}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=FillText}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding FontFamily, ElementName=FillText}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="{Binding FontStyle, ElementName=FillText}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding FontWeight, ElementName=FillText}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{Binding TextAlignment, ElementName=Padding}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="{Binding TextAlignment, ElementName=FillText}"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalAlignment, ElementName=FillText}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Canvas.Resources>
                    <!-- Offseting the Text block will create the outline, the margin is the Stroke Width-->
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource OutlinedTextStrokeTextBlock_Style}"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource OutlinedTextStrokeTextBlock_Style}"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="0,0,-1,0" Style="{DynamicResource OutlinedTextStrokeTextBlock_Style}"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,-1" Style="{DynamicResource OutlinedTextStrokeTextBlock_Style}"/>
                    <!-- Base TextBlock Will be the Fill -->
                    <TextBlock x:Name="FillText" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                               FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                               TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                               Style="{DynamicResource TbMediaOverlay_Style}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

as already mentioned, convert text to path

```
FormattedText t = new FormattedText
(
    "abcxyz",
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface(
    new FontFamily("Arial"),
    new FontStyle(),
    new FontWeight(),
    new FontStretch()),
    20,
    Brushes.Transparent
);

Geometry g = t.BuildGeometry(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));

Path p = new Path();
p.Fill = Brushes.White;
p.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
p.StrokeThickness = 1;
p.Data = g;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Blend you could convert the TextBlock to a Path, and then use the normal Stroke properties.  But I'm assuming you wanted something that you could make dynamic...

Otherwise I would think it would have to be some sort of bitmap effect or special brush.

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to Kent Boogaart's code which, while awesome, is missing a small detail. This is probably a little inaccurate in that it will only measure the fill and not the stroke but adding a couple of lines to `OnRender()` `Viewbox` will be able to get a handle on what to do with it (although, as with `TextBox`, not in preview).

```cs
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    this.EnsureGeometry();

    this.Width = this.formattedText.Width;
    this.Height = this.formattedText.Height;

    drawingContext.DrawGeometry(this.Fill, new Pen(this.Stroke, this.StrokeThickness), this.textGeometry);
}
```

I'm using this with two layers of text so the stroke appears to only be around the outside as follows. This will obviously not work straight away as it refers to specific images and fonts.

```xml
<Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <bd:OutlinedText x:Name="LevelTitleStroke" Text="Level" FontSize="80pt" FontFamily="/fonts/papercuts-2.ttf#Paper Cuts 2" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" StrokeThickness="15">
        <bd:OutlinedText.Stroke>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/GrungeMaps/03DarkBlue.jpg" Stretch="None" />
        </bd:OutlinedText.Stroke>
    </bd:OutlinedText>
</Viewbox>
<Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <bd:OutlinedText x:Name="LevelTitleFill" Text="Level" FontSize="80pt" FontFamily="/fonts/papercuts-2.ttf#Paper Cuts 2" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <bd:OutlinedText.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/GrungeMaps/03Red.jpg" Stretch="None" />
        </bd:OutlinedText.Fill>
    </bd:OutlinedText>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: You could draw the strokes first, followed by filling in.

Comment: It's more than a couple of lines to cater for stroke measurement, arrangement, and rendering. If pen line join is bevel or round instead of the default miter, the extra width and height will be the same as the stroke thickness, and the geometry origin should be offset by half of it.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve something similar to this as well.  The classes mentioned here were great, but weren't exactly what I was looking for, because it only really looked right if the text was large enough.  The text I was trying to display was around 10 - 11 font size, and the stroke was so large the letters sort of blended together.

Just to clarify, this text was supposed to be overlaid on a user-defined picture, which could have varying colors, and I wanted to ensure this text would show up.

I don't know if this is best practice or not, but this at least achieved the look I wanted (based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748273%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%29%3a)):

```
<Style x:Key="OutlinedTextBlockOuter" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <BlurEffect Radius="3.0"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="OutlinedTextBlockInner" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

Then for the actual TextBlocks, I combined two Outer styled TextBlocks because one was too light, and one Inner styled TextBlock:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource OutlinedTextBlockOuter}" Text="This is outlined text using BlurEffect"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource OutlinedTextBlockOuter}" Text="This is outlined text using BlurEffect"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource OutlinedTextBlockInner}" Text="This is outlined text using BlurEffect"/>
</Grid>
```

Alternatively, you could use the DropShadowEffect, which looked okay with using only two textboxes (although adding more DropShadowEffects with varying directions and lowered opacity may look even better):

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <TextBlock  Text="This is my outlined text using the DropShadowEffect" FontSize="10" Foreground="White">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="2" Opacity="0.75" Direction="315"/>
        </TextBlock.Effect>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock  Text="This is my outlined text using the DropShadowEffect" FontSize="10" Foreground="White">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="2" Opacity="0.75" Direction="135"/>
        </TextBlock.Effect>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I use `DropShadowEffect` with `ShadowDept="0"` and `BlurRadius="1"` which perfectly draws the outline without specifying same `TextBlock` twice like you showed.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add this to MeasureOverride so it would show single lines of text while using layout rounding. It worked fine when the text was wrapping though.

```
// return the desired size
return new Size(Math.Ceiling(_FormattedText.Width), Math.Ceiling(_FormattedText.Height));
```

Answer (score 0):

<TextBlock> has no decorative attributes itself. I would put it on a <Canvas> with a <Rectangle> and apply the stroke there.

Answer (score 0):

Could just use a Label instead.  It has more properties that you can play with.  Example:

```
  <Style x:Key="LeftBorderLabel" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Margin"  Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
  </Style>
```

Comment: True, but the BorderBrush and BorderThickness in this case apply to the border of the label, rather than outlining the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out tremendously!  Just in case anyone needs it in the future, here's the VB version (made StrokeThickness a double and added an Underline property):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Markup

Namespace CustomXaml

    Public Class OutlinedText
        Inherits FrameworkElement
        Implements IAddChild

        Private _textGeometry As Geometry

        Private Shared Sub OnOutlineTextInvalidated(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
            DirectCast(d, OutlinedText).CreateText()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRender(drawingContext As System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext)
            CreateText()
            drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Fill, New Pen(Stroke, StrokeThickness), _textGeometry)
        End Sub

        Public Sub CreateText()
            Dim fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal
            Dim fontWeight = FontWeights.Medium
            Dim fontDecoration = New TextDecorationCollection()

            If Bold Then fontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
            If Italic Then fontStyle = FontStyles.Italic
            If Underline Then fontDecoration.Add(TextDecorations.Underline)

            Dim formattedText = New FormattedText( _
                                Text, _
                                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), _
                                FlowDirection.LeftToRight, _
                                New Typeface(Font, fontStyle, fontWeight, FontStretches.Normal), _
                                FontSize, _
                                Brushes.Black _
                                )
            formattedText.SetTextDecorations(fontDecoration)

            _textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(New Point(0, 0))

            Me.MinWidth = formattedText.Width
            Me.MinHeight = formattedText.Height
        End Sub

        Public Property Bold As Boolean
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(BoldProperty), Boolean)
            End Get
            Set(value As Boolean)
                SetValue(BoldProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly BoldProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "Bold", _
            GetType(Boolean), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                False, _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Property Underline As Boolean
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(UnderlineProperty), Boolean)
            End Get
            Set(value As Boolean)
                SetValue(UnderlineProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly UnderlineProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "Underline", _
            GetType(Boolean), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                False, _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Property Fill As Brush
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(FillProperty), Brush)
            End Get
            Set(value As Brush)
                SetValue(FillProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly FillProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "Fill", _
            GetType(Brush), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSteelBlue), _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Property Font As FontFamily
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(FontProperty), FontFamily)
            End Get
            Set(value As FontFamily)
                SetValue(FontProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly FontProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "Font", _
            GetType(FontFamily), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                New FontFamily("Arial"), _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Property FontSize As Double
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(FontSizeProperty), Double)
            End Get
            Set(value As Double)
                SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly FontSizeProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "FontSize", _
            GetType(Double), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                CDbl(48.0), _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Property Italic As Boolean
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(ItalicProperty), Boolean)
            End Get
            Set(value As Boolean)
                SetValue(ItalicProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly ItalicProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "Italic", _
            GetType(Boolean), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                False, _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Property Stroke As Brush
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(StrokeProperty), Brush)
            End Get
            Set(value As Brush)
                SetValue(StrokeProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly StrokeProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "Stroke", _
            GetType(Brush), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Teal), _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Property StrokeThickness As Double
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty), Double)
            End Get
            Set(value As Double)
                SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly StrokeThicknessProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "StrokeThickness", _
            GetType(Double), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                CDbl(0), _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Property Text As String
            Get
                Return CType(GetValue(TextProperty), String)
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                SetValue(TextProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly TextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
            "Text", _
            GetType(String), _
            GetType(OutlinedText), _
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata( _
                "", _
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, _
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnOutlineTextInvalidated), _
                Nothing _
            ) _
        )

        Public Sub AddChild(value As Object) Implements System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild.AddChild

        End Sub

        Public Sub AddText(text As String) Implements System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild.AddText
            Me.Text = text
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Kent's solution in my custom control. It resulted in a null exception when using templatebinding against the text property.

I had to modify the MeasureOverride function like so:

```
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        this.EnsureFormattedText();

        if (this.formattedText == null)
        {
            this.formattedText = new FormattedText(
                                (this.Text == null) ? "" : this.Text,
                                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
                                this.FlowDirection,
                                new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, FontStretches.Normal),
                                this.FontSize,
                                Brushes.Black);
        }

        // constrain the formatted text according to the available size
        // the Math.Min call is important - without this constraint (which seems arbitrary, but is the maximum allowable text width), things blow up when availableSize is infinite in both directions
        this.formattedText.MaxTextWidth = Math.Min(3579139, availableSize.Width);
        this.formattedText.MaxTextHeight = availableSize.Height;

        // return the desired size
        return new Size(this.formattedText.Width, this.formattedText.Height);
    }
```

It should be noted that I did not thoroughly test this.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have another answer, I'll post it for the record.
I think it is a less elegant one, without using `Geometry`, `Path` and `FormattedText`, though simpler, and (if you know I'd like to know) might be faster to render ??
It basically had the same text 8 times, but shifted on all cardinal direction.

here is the code of my UserControl :

```
/// <summary>
/// User Control to display a Text with an outline
/// </summary>
public partial class OutlinedText : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region DependencyProperties

    /// <summary>
    /// The Text to render
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(OutlinedText), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    /// <summary>
    /// The size (thickness) of the Stroke
    /// </summary>
    public int StrokeSize
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StrokeSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StrokeSize.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeSize", typeof(int), typeof(OutlinedText), new PropertyMetadata(1));

    /// <summary>
    /// The Color of the Stroke
    /// </summary>
    public Brush StrokeColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(StrokeColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StrokeColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(OutlinedText), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    #endregion

    #region ctor
    public OutlinedText()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    } 
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and on XAML side :

```
<UserControl x:Class="NAMESPACE.OutlinedText"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IntegerInverterConverter x:Key="IntegerInverterConverterKey"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <!--Bottom Right ⬊ -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StrokeColor}"
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
               Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding StrokeSize}" Y="{Binding StrokeSize}"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <!--Top Left ⬉ -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StrokeColor}"                           
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
               Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding StrokeSize, Converter={StaticResource IntegerInverterConverterKey}}" Y="{Binding StrokeSize, Converter={StaticResource IntegerInverterConverterKey}}"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <!--Bottom Left ⬋ -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StrokeColor}"                       
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
               Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding StrokeSize, Converter={StaticResource IntegerInverterConverterKey}}" Y="{Binding StrokeSize}"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <!--Top Right ⬈ -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StrokeColor}"                           
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
               Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding StrokeSize}" Y="{Binding StrokeSize, Converter={StaticResource IntegerInverterConverterKey}}"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <!--Top ⬆ -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StrokeColor}"                           
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
               Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="{Binding StrokeSize, Converter={StaticResource IntegerInverterConverterKey}}"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <!--Bottom ⬇ -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StrokeColor}"                           
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
               Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="{Binding StrokeSize}"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <!--Right ➡ -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StrokeColor}"                           
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
               Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding StrokeSize}" Y="0"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <!--Left ⬅ -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StrokeColor}"
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
               Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding StrokeSize, Converter={StaticResource IntegerInverterConverterKey}}" Y="0"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Foreground}"
               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"
               FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontWeight}"                       
               FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontFamily}"
               Text="{Binding Text}" />
</Grid>
```

The used converter here is a simple *(-1) on an integer, to avoid using another property :

```
/// <summary>
/// Simple converter to return the negative of a given integer value
/// </summary>
public class IntegerInverterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int original=0;
        try 
        {
            original = (int)value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Warning(e, "Exception when casting a object to an integer. @IntegerInverterConverter.Convert()");
        }
        return -original;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
<local:OutlinedText Margin="WHATEVER" HorizontalAlignment="WHATEVER" VerticalAlignment="WHATEVER"
                                Text="Your Text" StrokeColor="WhiteSmoke" StrokeSize="2" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"
                                Foreground="Magenta"/>
```

Comment: I'd like to try this approach. It's missing the IntegerInverterConverter though. Could you please add it?

Comment: I added the code as you asked me. it is a really simple converter class with a straight forward code.