# White font with black border in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, fonts, textbox

as the title says, I would like to have a black font with a white border
in my `TextBox`.

How could it be achieved?

Cheers.

Comment: Your question title and body say the opposite. White with black border, or black with white border? :)

Comment: @Matt, yes, you are right :-) It does not matter, the idea would be probably the same ;-)))

Comment: Agreed :-)  But do you mean a border around the individual letters in the font, or a border around the entire TextBox?

Comment: @Matt, a border around the individual letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Blacklight controls @ http://blacklight.codeplex.com/. In particular look at the sample on http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/ **|** Visual Controls **|** TEXT **|** Stroke Text Block (Alpha).

Comment: @Jamie: were you ever able to implement/use Blacklight for this need?

Comment: I didn't use the Blacklight finally, however while looking at the code I found the solution suitable for me. Thus I can consider your answer as a good one. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to convert text into geometry objects with advanced formatting like outlines and fills for individual letters - you can find out more about how to do that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742190.aspx).

Having said that, I'm not sure that this is possible inside a TextBox. It may be for read-only text (TextBlock) only.

**Edit**

[This blog post](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/silverlaw/archive/2010/02/23/leather-stamped-textbox-style-silverlight-3.aspx) shows some advanced font rendering techniques inside a TextBox. It may be handy for you.

Comment: Also read these two http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf/97728#97728

Answer (score 3):

What I always do for that is set the font color to white and set a DropShadow effect on the text.

Next, play around with depth, angle (set to 0 or something) and blur and you should be able to get what you want.

Comment: allright, but how to apply DropShadow effect to FormattedText?

Answer (score 1):

A full class and example using Geometries:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/12/24/using-text-as-a-decorative-graphic.aspx