# Outer bevel effect on text in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible to apply an outer bevel effect to the label text in WPF?

[image]

as for me, the Glow effect should be sufficient:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to get Glow-effect on Text. Using the OutlinedText control from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf) which offers Stroke.

[image]

```
<local:OutlinedText FontSize="100"
                    Fill="Black"
                    Bold="True"
                    Stroke="White"
                    StrokeThickness="3"
                    Text="Glow">
    <local:OutlinedText.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                          Color="White"
                          Opacity="1"
                          BlurRadius="12"/>
    </local:OutlinedText.Effect>
</local:OutlinedText>
```

**Update**
This is the closest I've come to a Bevel effect but it doesn't work very well. Used the approach from [this link](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/ux/archive/2010/09/01/text-bevel-effect-in-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx).

[image]

```
<Style x:Key="ContentControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Name="Highlight" Foreground="#66FFFFFF" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    <TextBlock Name="Shadow" Margin="0,4,0,0" Foreground="#CC000000" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ContentControl Style="{DynamicResource ContentControlStyle1}" FontSize="101" Foreground="DarkGray" Content="Bevel"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not particularly happy with this 'solution':

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World!" Foreground="Red">
   <TextBlock.Effect>
      <BlurEffect Radius="1" KernelType="Box" />
   </TextBlock.Effect>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="Hello World!" />
```

Other option is to make your own pixel shader, I'm not very good at that so I'm afraid that I cant help you :/

edit: Better solution, still not bevel though.

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World!">
   <TextBlock.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="Red" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" />
   </TextBlock.Effect>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: ah, I saw the TextBlock had an effect, but I only messed around  with the DropShadow effect.  So, the Blur is kinda like a glow? I'll have to play with that.

Comment: @townsean ye, maybe DropShadowEffect is better to use, then you can skip the dual TextBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this could of work:

```
<Label Content="Hi there!">
<Label.BitmapEffect>
<OuterGlowBitmapEffect/>
</Label.BitmapEffect>
</Label>
```

I have NOT tested this in a label, but i has worked for me in other controls and shapes, also, check out all the effect list IntelliSense gives you :)

Comment: I tried `<Label.BitmapEffect><OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="White" GlowSize="5"/></Label.BitmapEffect>` didn't work.. (

Comment: by the way, there is a **`BevelBitmapEffect`** too, but I didn't achieve to apply it to a label text.

Comment: Try it on a textblock instead.... it should work, ive done it before now that i remember it... :p

Comment: BitmapEffect has been deprecated, that why it does not show anything in wpf 4. Your best shot is a custom PixelShader.

Comment: Are you serious? I could of swear i used it with .NET 4 before... also, i can still use bitmapeffects on buttons and other shapes whilst using .Net 4 :p

Comment: @Oggy - ahh! you're right! :( My default framework version is 3.5. UGH! Back to the drawing board. :)

Comment: I cant use OuterGlowBitmapEffect in a test app with .Net 4, but if I change the target framework to .Net 3.5 it works.

Comment: Really weird, im using .NET 4's DataGrid (NOT the WPF Preview one, the .NET 4 one) and i can still BitmapEffect buttons and stuff :S

Comment: @Oggy: how can I use PixelShader for the OuterGlow effect?

Comment: @serhio: If you REALLY want to got that way... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFPixelShader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ah, okay I understand your problem better.

Try something like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
       <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Blue" GlowSize="5" x:key="Glow" />
   </Grid.Resources>
   <Label Content="Blah!" BitmapEffect="{StaticResource Glow}" />
</Grid>
```

I get "Blah!" with a blue glow. Seems like a decent work around since Label's content can't be set twice.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: This won't work unless you're using Framework 3.5 as BitmapEffect has been deprecated. :(

Comment: Attention, I want to glow(bevel) *text* not *border*.

Comment: the glow isn't showing up just around the border of the label. the text is glowy too.

Answer (score 0):

Followintg Oggy's suggestion:

```
<Label.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" 
                      Color="Red" 
                      Opacity="1" 
                      ShadowDepth="0" />
</Label.Effect>
```