# Aero white glow in WPF?

Tags: wpf, aero

How do I add the Aero white glow behind a control in WPF?
I mean the glow like in a window's caption bar in Vista/7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This unrelated question seems to have the answer...
[Outer bevel effect on text in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334704/outer-bevel-effect-on-text-in-wpf)

I just needed a rectangle behind my text block...

```
    <Rectangle Height="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1, Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1, Path=HorizontalAlignment}" Margin="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1, Path=Margin}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1, Path=VerticalAlignment}" Width="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1, Path=ActualWidth}" Fill="White" Opacity="0.5">
        <Rectangle.Stroke>
            <SolidColorBrush />
        </Rectangle.Stroke>
        <Rectangle.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="10" KernelType="Gaussian" />
        </Rectangle.Effect>
    </Rectangle>
```

This is gonna do the trick for **any control** when you replace all the `"textBlock"`s in the code!
And it looks exactly the same as the aero glow!

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/wpf-sample-series-solution-for-the-obsolete-bitmapeffect-property-and-rendering-an-outerglowbitmapeffect/) help? The effect can be quite subtle but it does look alright.

I tried messing about with Pixel Shaders in WPF using Shazzam but it was a lot of work to achieve the same effect or better. They use a lot of "under the hood" stuff (such as double-pass shaders) of which the techniques aren't available to the WPF api.

Comment: @Vercas, it explains that using the replacement [DropShadowEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.aspx) class and setting the depth to zero will achieve similar results.

Comment: Gosh I didn't see that... But my post looks exactly like the glow in Windows. The drop shadow doesn't...