# How to add a border to the Text inside a TextBlock in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textblock

I am kinda new to WPF, dont know if the question is weird. I wanted to know if its possible to add a border around the text inside a textBlock.

EDIT:

As per suggestion I have tried both but without much success:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF0B232F" BorderThickness="2">
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF88BCCD" OpacityMask="Black"/>      
</Border>
```

and

```
<Label BorderBrush="#FF0B232F" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Content="TextBlock" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF88BCCD" />
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's all fine with your code. What do you dislike in it?

Comment: His question is how to "add a border around the text INSIDE(aka content of) a textBlock"... No one answered that question.  I would also like to know how to do this.

Comment: Look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf

Answer (score 5):

In such cases I use `Label` or `TextBlock` placed in `Border`.

Answer (score 4):

Both your approaches are correct, however, if you have the textblock/label inside a grid (or any other container) declared as you have, its contents will stretch. 
Try setting the VerticalAlignment and/or HorizontalAlignment to an appropriate setting (Top/Left, Center)..

something like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF0B232F" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF88BCCD" OpacityMask="Black"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: Filipe is correct - if the grid/contain contains other objects then the border will effectively cover the whole grid - VerticalAlignemnt and HorizontalAlignment fixes this. Not intuitive!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are asking for a full size TextBlock with a border overlay within the bounds of the TextBlock you could wrap it in a Grid and draw the borders over the top of the TextBlock like this...

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF88BCCD" OpacityMask="Black" />
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF0B232F" BorderThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

Because we haven't specified the grid row and column on the TextBlock and Border objects the border overlays on top of the TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to have a border around your textblock or any other control use :

```
 <Border>
      <TextBlock></TextBlock>
    </Border>
```

you set border properties like color ,cornerradius ,thickness,...