# How to outline TextBlock text in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, textblock, effect, outline

I would like to have a TextBlock outlined (add stroke to text, not the TextBlock rectangle) in WP 7.1 but have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf

Comment: Put TextBlock inside a Border

Comment: @Ku6opr: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I need to outline the text itself, not the TextBlock rectangle.

Comment: @Xin: Unfortunately this doesn't work for either Silverlight or WP7...

Comment: If the text is static you could create an Image with the Outline and show it instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this blog writeup](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/silverlight-3-effects-baby)  I am not sure if that is 100% what you want but there are several TextEffects you can apply to the text itself, you can also create your own text effects. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.texteffect.aspx) is not highly informative.  I did however find [this](http://sltext.codeplex.com/) on codeplex which may be exactly what the doctor ordered.

Comment: Works well for Silverlight, but the WP7 Silverlight flavor does not support the Effects. Go figure. I guess it was hurting performance and got taken out between CTP and WP7 RTM...