# Windows 8 C#/XAML - Create a border around textblock text

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm creating an app for the Windows 8 app store and I'm pretty new to the XAML UI stuff. What I want to do is create a black border around the actual text in the textblock. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the textblock:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TopLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Top Label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="48"/>
```

Comment: You would have to use DirectWrite to do this

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate please?

Comment: You can use directwrite to generate text outline convert it to path object and render path in the xaml app.

Comment: I hate to act like a total noob but could you possibly share some sample code with me. I'm fairly new to this framework and SDK. Thanks either way.

Answer (score 5):

Use Border control :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.border.aspx

something like this :

```
<Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0">
  <TextBlock x:Name="TopLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Top Label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="48"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: That only put a box around the label. I'm trying to outline the actual text. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term you are looking for is 'Stroke', other SO users have noticed that this affect appears to be absent from the shipped feature set.

The following question/solution should meet your needs - its based on WPF but both Windows 8 and WPF make use of XAML : [Apply Stroke to Text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93650/218159)

Alternatively theres an informative MSDN article about it (again aimed at WPF but the principles should be the same) : [How to: Create Outlined Text (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816.aspx)

I hope this helps!