# Text effect to enhance readability of small fonts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, text, readability

In a view I have a smaller font, foreground is white and background is dark grey.

At the moment I use a drop shadow effect like

```
 <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0"
    Opacity="0.99"
    ShadowDepth="1"
    Direction="270"
    Color="Black"
```

This looks zoomed as this:

[image: picture of text effect]

It works good on bigger fontsizes, but not very good on small scales as can be seen here:

[image: Picture of smaller size text effect]

**What would be a good text effect to enhance overall readability?**

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf) which uses an outer stroke around the text,
but it does not work at all on smaller fontsizes.

Comment: No text effect.  Like standard black on white.

Comment: I believe a zoom or scale effect would enhance the readability of the smaller fonts.

Comment: `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` might improve the rendered text using a small size.

Comment: Yes, the TextFormattingMode Display improves it a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness:

As@sa_ddam213 said use TextFormattingMode.
Furthermore you can experiment with the Anti-Aliasing algorithms via TextRenderingMode.
If you use ClearType, you can additionally experiment with ClearTypeHint.

Alternatives are use larger text or a font specially designed for small sizes like a pixel font.

Comment: Can you tell more about the pixelfont? At the moment I use Segoe UI and it performs not very well.

Comment: Sure, LMGTFY, for example http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php free pixel fonts, also called bitmap fonts designed to be displayed at very small sizes, usually you do not want any anti aliasing effects on them