# Apply stroke to textblock in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a `Silverlight` app where I want to give my `textblock` an outline (*not* the textblock, the *characters* themselves), otherwise known as `stroke`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf) which works for `WPF`, but is there a way to accomplish this when working with `XAML/Silverlight` (`PresentationFramework` is not a `Silverlight` assembly)? Is there an existing implementation?

Comment: Is converting the text to a `Path` an option? or is it dynamic?

Comment: @ChrisW. Text is dynamic, yes.

Comment: Only way I could think of doing this reasonably easily without a lot of code behind is build a quick `ContentControl` that applies a couple `DropShadowEffect` outlines in different directions to its `ContentPresenter` and just load your text through it to get the same effect.

Answer (score 9):

Going with @Chris W. idea, I came up with this code, although not the finest solution, it works:

```
<StackPanel>

    <!-- With DropShadow -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFFF0000" Text="With DropShadow" FontSize="16">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="1" Color="#FF000000" />
        </TextBlock.Effect>
    </TextBlock>

     <!-- No DropShadow -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFFF0000" Text="No DropShadow" FontSize="16" />

</StackPanel>
```