# Windows Phone how to add text ouline?

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, text, windows-phone-8.1

I start develop for WP and, i need do simple think - add to text border.

Something like this

[image]

In Android i do this very simple

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        final ColorStateList textColor = getTextColors();

        TextPaint paint = this.getPaint();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeMiter(10);
        this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gs_ColorWhite));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(48);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        setTextColor(textColor);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

But, i can't find how to do this in Windows Phone platform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that kind of outline is supported on Windows Phone.

See [WP 8.1 Text-Outline question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681319/windows-phone-8-1-runtime-text-outline),

However I think it's pretty easy to do with [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) with their `Canvas.Geometry` from text. [Win2D release note](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win2d/archive/2015/09/28/win2d-1-5-0-printing-and-text-outline-geometry.aspx).

Basically create your own control with Win2D -> Create the Text Geometry with the text with the correct properties -> Paint on canvas -> Paint your other text.