# Can I have a stroke around the letters in a TextBlock?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Is there any way I can add a stroke to the letters of a TextBlock, but I can't seem to figure out the properties:

```
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World">
        <TextBlock.Resources>
            <Stroke ?>
```

I cant seem to find the right documentation, as I suspect is not the same as the WPF?

Comment: That is not something that you can just set. You would need to have a font that already has a stroke defined

Comment: If the text is Static you can convert it to a path.

Answer (score 0):

Kent Boogaart solved your conundrum in 2008. Please redirect your focus to his nice answer:

[Apply stroke to a textblock in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Generally links as answers are discouraged, and this answer in particular is for WPF and is like [this example on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816(v=vs.110).aspx) whereas WP8 is more based on Silverlight, just as a side note.

Comment: No use typing another mans question if it so nicely answered on another thread. However as for WPF vs WP8 - spot on.

Comment: If there's already another mans question matching the criteria then mark it as a duplicate to be closed. :)