# Outlined font effect for text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, text, fonts, outlining

I was looking for a way to create an outline for some text in WPF to make it more distinguishable from the background. The original look I am trying to mimick is the following

[image]

You will notice that the font is really small which makes this problem very difficult. All controls and snippets I have found that outline text are drawing the outline **in** the letters and not around them which makes those controls a bad choice in my case. Even something simple as drawing shadows to fake a border is not enough

[image]

I was curious whether you know of some controls that can outline a text by drawing the outline **outside** of the letters which allows me to use small font sizes. Alternatively do you think sprite fonts which are used in games very often are a good approach? If so, are there any libraries/controls you can suggest?

Comment: For me, the second text style looks more distinguishable than the first one.

Comment: @Kirenenko The second style has white instead of a jade text color (refer to red text on red background in the first style) and it it is slightly larger. Furthermore the picture of the first style has a lower quality.

Comment: Could you add a drop shadow to the text or perhaps draw it twice, once in black & slightly larger and then again in red directly over the top? No idea how that would look though.

Comment: Alternatively explicitly set the background of text to black and centre it over the progress bar rather than stretching it.

Comment: @ChrisF Drawing it twice right on top of itself (with different font sizes) will probably result in distortions the longer the text gets. I guess one has to draw each letter separately and then merge them to one image programmatically.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic yeah, that did cross my mind too. Probably not the best idea then ;)

Comment: @ChrisF Please refer to my own answer to this question - your adapted suggestion works surprisingly well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply stroke to a textblock in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being I want to leave a small snippet which helped me create a very decent result so far which looks like this:

[image]

I am using multiple `TextBlock` elements inside a `Canvas` and overlaying them as [ChrisF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) suggested. Surprisingly this turned out to look better than expected with less distortions because I don't have to use an increased font size.

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource TestString}" FontSize="18"
               FontFamily="BigNoodleTitling" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Left="2" />
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource TestString}" FontSize="18"
               FontFamily="BigNoodleTitling" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Left="4" />
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource TestString}" FontSize="18"
               FontFamily="BigNoodleTitling" Canvas.Top="4" Canvas.Left="2" />
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource TestString}" FontSize="18"
               FontFamily="BigNoodleTitling" Canvas.Top="4" Canvas.Left="4" />
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource TestString}" FontSize="18"
               FontFamily="BigNoodleTitling" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="3"
               Foreground="#de5f5f" />
</Canvas>
```

**I am still interested in alternative solutions!**

Comment: You could try <Text.Effect><Blur> it works ok, maybe not as well as your example though.

Comment: Here's another way to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-outlined-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8