# TextBox how to make it stand out from bitmap below

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, effects

I have a textBox on an image stacked one above the other.
The image may vary and so the text may be hidden by the colour below.
I am searching for an effect like the one in the pic

[image]

so that whatever the background light or dark the image stands always out.

[image]

I've tried dropshadow  or blur effect but didn't work or didn't managed to make it work effectively.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your Fontfamily, Fontsize , Stroke as your wish and the OutlinedTextBlock class is in [Apply stroke to a textblock in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf). Make sure you have implemented the namespace of OutlinedTextBlock

```
 <local:OutlinedTextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="28pt" FontWeight="ExtraBold" TextWrapping="Wrap" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="White">
            Text
        </local:OutlinedTextBlock>
```