# How to set a namespace for custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

I have been implementing this solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf/) to make an outlinedTextbox.

I have created a test project and added directly in the main namespace and it works.

Now I want to add it to a library (HelperLib) and want to use it in whatever program of mine I want. For example here the program is called pcdLoggerS2.

[image]

but when I add it to my xaml it says that

[image]

so it's a matter of namespaces.
Therefore I have add this

```
xmlns:local="clr-HelperLib"
```

in my definition  of my Base:WindowViewBase but nothing has changed but it's really in that namespace!

[image]

--ADD FOR DAVID---
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you've added the HelperLib project as a reference to your test project.

Open PcdLogger and right click on References, and add that project as a reference.  Until you do this, the XAML in your test project will not be able to find the correct assembly.

Additionally, when you reference a namespace, from another assembly, you need to add that information to the namespace declaration in your XAML.

(See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514546%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

As an example:
(I would suggest leaving local for your local namespaces)

```
xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:HelperLib;assembly=HelperLib"
```

EDIT:
Additionally, Visual Studio's intellisense is fond of telling you that the namespace, or class, does not exist until you have built the project.  You may have to rebuild and/or close/reopen the xaml file for intellisense to cooperate again.

Comment: I have added your line and again it says: The name OutlinedTextBox does not exist in namespace "clr-namespace:HelperLib;Assembly=BelperLib" but if I right click and go to definition it leads  me to the right class. The helperLib is added as an additional project. What else might be wrong?

Comment: Did you misspell HelperLib (BelperLib) or is that the actual error?
Also, have you attempted to run it?  The editor likes to, frequently, tell you that something doesn't exist, in XAML, if you haven't rebuilt, yet.

Comment: Naaa that is so STUPID!! it works but the editor keeps on saying it's wrong. So please post it as a solution so that i can reward you. And then: am I bound not to use the editor anymore?!?!?!

Comment: I've added the additional information to this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

check Namespace  of you class.

`HelperLib` its name of a class, but not namespace.

[image: example]

Comment: Please see the penultimate picture added.

Comment: See answer from @David. You must call `namespace.classname` in code for external libraries or use `using` keyword.

Comment: Did you add reference to the project with library?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelperLib"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.