# How does a WPF Label Render a String as Text?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, text, label

I'm attempting to extend a Label control to support stroking the text ( sort of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf) questions answer, but I want to extend a Label to do it rather than write a brand new ( ish ) control ).

I've had a measure of success but I hit a wall in which I can't find how the Label renders text. If I could figure out how that happens ( and override it ) then I could add a few properties to my extended Label class ( a brush and a double ) and be all set.

This is what I have so far :

```
public class StrokedLabel : Label {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        StrokeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Stroke",
            typeof( Brush ),
            typeof( StrokedLabel ),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                Brushes.Red,
                ( S, E ) => ( S as StrokedLabel ).InvalidateVisual( ) ) ),
        StrokeWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "StrokeWidth",
            typeof( double ),
            typeof( StrokedLabel ),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                2.0D,
                ( S, E ) => ( S as StrokedLabel ).InvalidateVisual( ) ) );

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Stroke Brush.
    /// </summary>
    public Brush Stroke {
        get { return this.GetValue( StrokeProperty ) as Brush; }
        set { this.SetValue( StrokeProperty, value ); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Stroke Width
    /// </summary>
    public double StrokeWidth {
        get { return ( double )this.GetValue( StrokeWidthProperty ); }
        set { this.SetValue( StrokeWidthProperty, value ); }
    }

    protected override void OnRender( DrawingContext drawingContext ) {
        if ( !( this.Content is string ) )
            base.OnRender( drawingContext );
        else {
            drawingContext.DrawGeometry(
                this.Foreground,
                new Pen(
                    this.Stroke,
                    this.StrokeWidth ),
                new FormattedText(
                    this.Content.ToString( ),
                    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
                    this.FlowDirection,
                    new Typeface(
                        this.FontFamily,
                        this.FontStyle,
                        this.FontWeight,
                        this.FontStretch ),
                    this.FontSize,
                    this.Foreground ).BuildGeometry( new Point( 0.0D, 0.0D ) ) );
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried tracing the chain of inheritance and I've made it as far as `UIElement` which defines the `OnRender` method, but I can't find where in the chain of inheritance that method is actually used ( or if it's even involved ).

I feel like the text is rendered within the ContentControl ( from which the Label directly inherits ) but I can't find where in that control the text is rendered. Is it rendered in the Content Control, or is it rendered in what the Content Control inherits ( the Control class )?

In which class ( and through which method(s) ) is a string rendered as text?

Comment: It's been ages and i can't test it right now but: I think it was done via the content control functionality which tries to resolve a content template via its default template selector ([can be overridden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) . If the selector finds a `string` it returns a template containing a `TextBlock`. I think you can style said `TextBlock` via `Application.Resources` which apply across template boundaries.

Comment: Wait, it's an `AccessText`, obviously, as you want the underlining of the access key given by the "_" in front of said key in the string.

Answer (score 0):

As i'm a bit inquisitive i looked this up again properly. Here's what happens in the static `ContentPresenter` constructor:

```
// Default template for strings when hosted in ContentPresener with RecognizesAccessKey=true
template = new DataTemplate();
text = CreateAccessTextFactory();
text.SetValue(AccessText.TextProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(ContentProperty));
template.VisualTree = text;
template.Seal();
s_AccessTextTemplate = template;
```

```
// Default template selector
s_DefaultTemplateSelector = new DefaultSelector();
```

It creates an `AccessText` template that is stored in a private field with an internal property accessor (along with a handful of other default templates) and the default template selector.

When a template is resolved `ChooseTemplate` is invoked which contains this:

```
...
// if that failed, try the default TemplateSelector
if (template == null)
{
    template = DefaultTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(content, this);
}
```

In the `DefaultSelector`'s `SelectTemplate` method there is the following call if no template is found:

```
...
if ((s = item as string) != null)
    template = ((ContentPresenter)container).SelectTemplateForString(s);
```

`SelectTemplateForString`:

```
...
if (this.RecognizesAccessKey && s.IndexOf(AccessText.AccessKeyMarker) > -1)
{
    template = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(format)) ?
        AccessTextContentTemplate : FormattingAccessTextContentTemplate;
}
```

So here either the static template which was created in the constructor is chosen or one that is created dynamically using the `ContentStringFormat` value.

How you change that is up to you, though personally i am not a fan messing with default functionality (especially if it impacts keyboard accessibility).

Comment: But a label doesn't inherit a content presenter. A label inherits a `ContentControl`. Did you mean `ContentControl` or `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: @Will: Can't quite trace it back and don't have the tools at hand currently but i think the default template of `ContentControl` uses a `ContentPresenter` for it's content related properties. That is true for almost all controls, like `TabViews`, which uses one for the selected tab's content. (For the tabs themselves and other list based content an `ItemsPresenter` is used.)

Comment: @Will: If you want to dig into what is generated you can use something like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). You can also do that manually using the `VisualTreeHelper` which i have used before to write a poor man's version of Snoop.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it. I was using dnSpy but oh. my. god. the only thing that I learned from that is I don't know jack $#!t...

Comment: @Will: Well, WPF is rather huge and complex but also a masterpiece of a framework in my opinion.

Comment: Uhg... Snoop reveals that text is rendered from within a TextBlock... and the TextBlock OnRender override is sealed... FFFFF... That means that I probably will have to writer my own ( or use the one that already exists... or just alter the existing TextBlock code... ).

Comment: @Will: Well, doing low level rending related thinks is hardly ever pretty, i usually avoid that at all costs.