# How to put an outlined textBlock (or any other control) in a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am using this [outlined textBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf) that with the solution proposed by Javier G. works like a charm. I put it in a library so now it's HelperLib:OutlinedTextBlock.
Now I would like to put it in a TextBox.

So what I tried is:

- Put the OutlinedTextBox as a child of a TextBlock but that didn't work since it's not accepting it as a child.
- Use a RichTextBox and the put it inside a FlowDocument but something went wrong since a got a Runtime error

  - Use a template but again Runtime error.

If the fact of putting the outlinedTextBox makes it too peculiar I think that this can be rethought as putting anyother control inside a textbox.

I think the solution is close but somehow it still escapes me...
--EDIT--
There is an additiona problem which I have never encountered:
I have named my control otbQuery but it doesn't show up in the code!!! Why???

```
<TextBox Name="tbxQuery" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" Width="200" Background="Transparent" CaretBrush="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="3">
    <TextBox.Template>
       <ControlTemplate>
          <Border BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="3">
             <Grid>
         -----> <HelperLib:OutlinedTextBlock Name="otbQuery" Margin="1" Fill ="White" Stroke="Red" Text="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=cp, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp" Content="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TextBlock.Foreground="Transparent"/>
              </Grid>
          </Border>
       </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>             
</TextBox>
```

you can see the error here and no valid quick fix is proposed

[image]

Comment: Uh?? What happened why was the solution posted deleted?? It sounded good but still couldn't test it  :-o

Comment: I deleted it because even though it displayed well and you could bind data from a ViewModel to it, you could not actually type in the TextBox.  Not a very useful TextBox.

Comment: Thank you the same... so no other solution? I don't need to bind it but yes I need to type in it....

Comment: Ok, undeleted and edited the solution.  It works, but it's a bit of an ugly hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override the `ControlTemplate` of the `TextBox` control in order to make that happen.  Below is a simple example of how to do that, and still have the `TextBox.Text` property bound to the `Text` property of the `TexBlock`.

```
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Margin="1" 
                                        Foreground="Red"
                                        Text="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=cp, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp"
                                            Content="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                                TextBlock.Foreground="Transparent"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TextBox.Template>
        </TextBox>
```

Where I have put a standard `TextBlock` inside the `ControlTemplate`, you would put your custom `TextBlock` control.

**EDIT**

The above solution works, but it's a serious kludge.  Basically, it puts a transparent `ContentPresenter` on top of the `TextBlock` .  The `TextBlock` display the text in the manner you want and the `ContentPresenter` allows you to type in the `TextBox`.

One problem that still exists is that the cursor bar does not show up when clicking on, or typing in the `TextBox`.  I suspect that problem could be overcome with some more styling done to the template of the `TextBox`.

Comment: Your solution is great!!! And I will mark it solved but I'd appreciate it if you could make an additional effort. The fact that the cursor doesn't show up makes it completely useless. I've got to use it in countless places in my program and I can't solve the problem myself. ....Thanks