# text with an empty/transparent interior and black sides c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhIsX.png)
Hello, is there a way to achieve the design shown in the image using XAML code? I'm having difficulty finding a clear answer on this topic. I want to avoid using images in my app. What is the fastest way to achieve this — using paths in XAML code, creating a custom user control, or utilizing TextBlock or Label?

Comment: Please do not post links to images, pose the image. And please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I hope this topic will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93650/apply-stroke-to-a-textblock-in-wpf/

Comment: See also [Drawing Formatted Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drawing-formatted-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).